# how to get a background color to scale to window size?

Tags: html, css

I have a gradient background color in the body on my CSS page. I have tried numerous configurations with padding and margin with no success to get the color to scale for different size screens. It is not an issue for the top, left or right, only with the bottom. For a quick fix I had the bottom padding of the body set to 10%.
I would rather make it so that the background color scales to fit window sizes. Thanks in advance! here is a link to the page, it really only happens in IE, or a full window.  http://jstrobel.sheridan-college.com/index.html

```
body {  
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#003399), to(#6699cc));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
background: linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003399',  
    endColorstr='#6699cc');
zoom: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
 }
 #wrapper { margin: auto;
       width: 1060px; 
    min-width: 1060px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
   -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
   -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
   -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
 }
 #container { background: #ffeeee;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#ffeeee), to(#6699cc));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffeeee, #6699cc);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
     background: linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffeeee',   
         endColorstr='#6699cc');
     zoom: 1; 
     min-width: 1060px;
         font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:     `background-attachment: fixed;`
 to your body.

**The solution is:**

```
html {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#003399), to(#6699cc));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003399',  
        endColorstr='#6699cc');
}
```

---

```
body {  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#003399), to(#6699cc));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    background: linear-gradient(#003399, #6699cc);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003399',  
        endColorstr='#6699cc');
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 #wrapper { 
    margin: auto;
    width: 1060px; 
    min-width: 1060px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
    -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
 }
 #container { 
    background: #ffeeee;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#ffeeee), to(#6699cc));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffeeee, #6699cc);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffeeee, #6699cc);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffeeee',   
         endColorstr='#6699cc');
    zoom: 1; 
    min-width: 1060px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
```

**Edit:**
And add:

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
```

Demo:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wE3HJ8W.png]

Comment: That didn't seem to effect anything

Comment: @StickintheMud edited the answer for u, try to add a height off 100%

Comment: humm didn't change anything for me but I am using IE 9

Comment: margin: auto;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 3%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        height: 100%;

Comment: Could you try to put the gradient of your background between `html { .. }`

Comment: @StickintheMud nice, good luck with your website. If my answer solve your question you can accept it :)